# TEdit onclick select all?

Tags: delphi, onclick, delphi-2010, textselection

How to select all text of a TEdit1 whenever user click on it or click to select some text of it

Comment: I'm confused. Please clarify your question. Do you want to know how to set TEdit to the appropriate behavior or how to do to do it programmatically?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> How to select all text of a TEdit1 whenever user click on it

Select Edit1 in the VCL editor and double-click on the `OnClick` event:

[image]

```
procedure TForm13.Edit1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Edit1.SelectAll;
end;
```

You can also link this event to another control like a button.
Select the button, choose  and click on the `V` arrow to select an event you want to link.

[image]

Now both `Edit1.OnClick` and `Button1.OnClick` link to the same event.

Comment: This is just an event handler. It must must be wired somewhere to be triggered.

Comment: I mean wired to an event property of a VCL component. Presumably Edit1 judging by its name but it might also not be so.

Comment: @Johan Have you tried using such an edit control. Try placing the caret with your mouse.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I wanted to keep it simple, but put an extra test in to only do `selectall` if the edit does not have the focus. Anyway good point, the simple change makes it much less annoying.

Comment: It's too late to put the test in the OnClick. The best you can do is to post a select all message to the window in `OnEnter`.

Comment: Reverted the edit i don't want to overcomplicate this with postmessage. I just wanted to show in general how to link code to events.

Answer (score 22):

It can be quite dangerous to do anything beyond the default behaviour of the `TEdit` control. Your users know how the standard Windows controls behave and any deviation from this is likely to cause confusion.

By default the [`AutoSelect`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TCustomEdit.AutoSelect) property is set to `True`.

> Determines whether all the text in the edit control is automatically selected when the control gets focus.
>
> Set **AutoSelect** to select all the text when the edit control gets focus. **AutoSelect** only applies to single-line edit controls.
>
> Use **AutoSelect** when the user is more likely to replace the text in the edit control than to append to it.

When this property is `True`, the entire contents of the edit control are selected when it gets the focus by means of keyboard action. If the control gets the focus by a mouse click then the contents will not all be selected. In that case you simply press <kbd>CTRL+A</kbd> to select all. A double click will select the word underneath the mouse. This is all standard behaviour implemented by the underlying Windows control.

---

If you change the select in response to the `OnClick` event, as per the currently selected answer, then you will find that it is impossible to move the caret with a mouse click. This is exceedingly counter-intuitive behaviour.

This is a classic example of why you need to be very careful about changing the behaviour of a control from its default. It's simply very easy not to miss a particular use case when testing but when your users get hold of the program, they are sure to find all such wrinkles.

What you could safely do is to call `SelectAll` from `OnDblClick`. This would, I believe have no annoying side-effects.

Another option would be to call `SelectAll` when the focus switched to the edit control, but not every time you click in the control. This might feel a little odd to the user, but I personally think it would be reasonable to take this course of action. If you want to do this you need to handle the `OnEnter` event of your edit control:

```
procedure TForm1.Edit1Enter(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PostMessage(Edit1.Handle, EM_SETSEL, 0, -1);
end;
```

Comment: Nice explanation and opinion article.

Comment: I was just about to ask a similar question, but found this first.  Excellent!   Thanks, guys.

Answer (score 3):

How to select some text of a TEdit1 whenever user click on it:

```
procedure TForm1.Edit1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Edit1.SelStart:= 1;
  Edit1.SelLength:= 2;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

You must use OnMouseUp;

```
procedure cxMRUEdit1MouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
 if Button=mbLeft then cxMRUEdit1.SelectAll;
end;
```